# PHP - Remove last character of file

Tags: php, file-io, trim

I have a little php script that removes the last character of a file.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($path);
rtrim($contents);
$contents = substr($contents, 0, -1);
$fh = fopen($path, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $contents);
fclose($fh);
```

So it reads in the file contents, strips off the last character and then truncates the file and writes the string back to it.
This all works fine.

My worry is that this file could contain a lot of data and the file_get_contents() call would then hold all this data in memory which could potentially max out my servers memory.

Is there a more efficient way to strip the last character from a file?

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this

```
$fh = fopen($path, 'r+') or die("can't open file");

$stat = fstat($fh);
ftruncate($fh, $stat['size']-1);
fclose($fh);
```

For more help see [this](http://php.net/ftruncate)

Comment: That appears to truncate the file to 0..? -- Ahh maybe because fopen is using w. Setting it to r doesn't seem to work though ?

Comment: Thanks very much azat. Works great now :)

Comment: Elegant solution, never knew about that function even in C

Comment: If you want to add characters after you trimmed the trailing character, you need to `fseek()` to the current size. If you don't, you'll get null characters between the new size and the old size of the file. 
`$position = fstat($fh)['size'] - 1;`
`ftruncate($fh, $position);`
`fseek($fh, $position);`

Comment: Worked for me to remove last char A0 in CSV files