# fputcsv adds a line ending on the last element

Tags: php

I have a basic PHP script that creates a csv file from an array. Here is an example of the code:

```
$array = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6]
];

$handle = fopen('test.csv', 'w');

foreach($array as $v)
    fputcsv($handle, $v);

fclose($handle);
```

The resulting file always has a blank line at the end of the file, because fputcsv doesn't know that this is the last line. Any (simple) ideas on how to prevent this?

EDIT:

The original question is now irrelevant (to me, but maybe someone will need to do this). fputcsv is supposed to add a new line, even at the end of the document, and this is the expected behavior of all csv files.

I marked the answer that solves the original question, even though it isn't relevant to me anymore.

So in my context, I needed to check if the last line (or any line) of the array is NULL (otherwise PHP will through up a Warning that fputcsv's 2nd parameter is null). Here is my updated script if anyone is interested:

```
$array = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6]
];

$handle = fopen('test.csv', 'w');

foreach($array as $v)
    if($v != NULL)
        fputcsv($handle, $v);

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: All lines should have a line ending after them. A blank line would be two newlines in a row.

Comment: What's wrong with having a blank line at the end of the file?  Why is that unwanted?  I ran your code and Excel showed 2 rows when I opened the file.

Comment: The script is actually half of a class that takes a csv, converts it to an array, then back to a new csv (so that you can use PHP to alter the CSV). I don't want any extra lines that weren't in the original document.

Comment: @user1564018: The "extra line" in your file shouldn't cause any problems.  This is not a problem you need to be worrying about.

Comment: For example, if I ran a csv with the extra line ending through the script, I get:

    Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given

Comment: @user1564018: Then you are probably just handling it wrong.  You need to check if `fgetcsv` returns `FALSE`.  If it does, stop.  It works fine for me: https://eval.in/68594  Check the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: So basically, I shouldn't be worried that some other script will see the new line at the end of a csv file that MY script makes, because the new line is expected, right?

Comment: @user1564018: Yes, exactly.  It's up to the script/program *reading* the CSV to handle the new line at the end.  The docs for `fgetcsv` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) show how to do this in PHP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this solution on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8354413/1564018

```
$stat = fstat($handle);
ftruncate($handle, $stat['size']-1);
```

I added these two lines after fputcsv() and they removed the last new line character, removing the blank line at the end of the file.

Comment: This is "technically" the answer to the original question, but the question ended up being irrelevant, because I didn't realize that the new line at the end of the document is expected. See the comments.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks! I wish I didn't have to deal with this problem, but I'm producing CSV files for processing by MS Word's mail merge function…a truly wonderful thing…unfortunately, I can't directly blame the MS devs since the spec is ambiguous on how the last line of a CSV file should end [https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180] but their solution is to throw an error at the user that the last record is empty when the "empty line" is processed. Thanks for helping me vanquishing that error message.

Answer (score 2):

Add exit(); at the end, after fclose(handle);

Comment: Can you explain how that does **not** add a new line at the end of the file? Have  a look at the other answers

Comment: I couldn't explain why but it works for me

Answer (score 1):

Like @Barmar says, all lines have a line ending, let's say \n. What you see as a blank line at the end of the file is your editor doing that. A truly blank line is two line-ending characters in succession. (\n\n for example)

Imagine you have a blank file:

```
(EOF)
```

If you fputcsv this: ***array(0,"hello",3323)*** you get

```
(0,hello,3323\nEOF)
```

given PHP docs:

fputcsv() formats a line (passed as a fields array) as CSV and write it (**terminated by a newline**) to the specified file handle.

A blank line in your editor is expected then. But in the file there's no such thing.

Answer (score 1):

`fputcsv` adds a new line after each line, that's how it works.  From the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php):

> fputcsv() formats a line (passed as a fields array) as CSV and write it (terminated by a newline)

A new line at the end of a file is not an error, or something you need to worry about.  Don't try to remove it, just leave it.

In the comments, you mention you got an error:

> Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given

This is probably because you are not using `fgetcsv` correctly.  It returns `FALSE` when it hits the end of the file (the new line).  The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) show you how to use it correctly:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
}
```