# Handle csv with php in for loop and write them back

Tags: php, arrays, csv

i'm struggling with a php code that must open more than 1 csv, handle its content and write back on a different way that was initially.

So, i have all csv's on rows, and i wanna parse them and split them in columns on 2 rows.

**The code looks like:**

```
$currentDirOtherCSV = __DIR__ . "/uploads/" . $ftp_location . "partial_crawler_data/";
    $files_other_CSV    = scandir($partial_crawler_data, 1);

for($i = 0; $i < count($files_other_CSV) - 2; $i++){
    $csvFileToOpen  = file($currentDirOtherCSV . $files_other_CSV[$i]);

    $screamingDataFirst = [];
    foreach ($csvFileToOpen as $line) {
        $screamingDataFirst[] = str_getcsv($line);
    }

    // remove header from csv
    array_shift($screamingDataFirst);
    array_shift($screamingDataFirst);        

    // handle array to export it on 2 rows
    $theExportArray = [[],[]];

    for($j = 0; $j < count($screamingDataFirst); $j++){
        if(!array_key_exists('1', $screamingDataFirst[$j])) {
            $screamingDataFirst[$j][1] = "";
        }
    }

    foreach ($screamingDataFirst as $key => $row){
        $theExportArray[0][$key] = $row[0];
        $theExportArray[1][$key] = $row[1];
    }

    print_r($theExportArray);

    // edit csv file remote
    $new_csv_data = fopen($currentDirOtherCSV . $files_other_CSV[$i], "w");
    foreach($theExportArray as $row){
        fputcsv($new_csv_data, $row, ";");
    }

    fclose($new_csv_data);
}
```

**The csv looks like:**

```
"Page Titles - Duplicate"
"Address","Title 1"
"http://www.seloo.ro/index.php?route=product/product&path=60&product_id=123","Scaun tapitat Alb"
"http://www.seloo.ro/index.php?route=product/product&path=60&product_id=122","Scaun tapitat Alb"
"http://www.seloo.ro/index.php?route=product/product&path=60&product_id=121","Scaun tapitat Alb"
"http://www.seloo.ro/index.php?route=product/product&path=60&product_id=127","Scaun tapitat Alb"
```

**so i get this array by parsing it:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.seloo.ro/index.php?route=product/product&path=60&product_id=123
            [1] => http://www.seloo.ro/index.php?route=product/product&path=60&product_id=122
            [2] => http://www.seloo.ro/index.php?route=product/product&path=60&product_id=121
            [3] => http://www.seloo.ro/index.php?route=product/product&path=60&product_id=127
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Scaun tapitat Alb
            [1] => Scaun tapitat Alb
            [2] => Scaun tapitat Alb
            [3] => Scaun tapitat Alb
        )

)
```

**EDIT**

That must be:

```
http://www.seloo.ro/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=95;http://www.seloo.ro/index.php?route=product/product&path=59&product_id=95;http://www.seloo.ro/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=94;
"Masa New vision";"Masa flori lila";"Masa flori lila";
```

**Problem:**
I thought that if i open the file, handle it, push it back modified in the csv and close (`fclose`) then do it again untill no csv, will handle them 1 by one...
But it only write in a single csv, rest of them arent touched

Am i missing something?

**UPDATE**

The script works fine.
The problem was that i have tried to update the unuploaded files on the server.
Script was faster than upload.

Thank you all and sorry, i should check that earlier

Comment: Ok, forget my points on scandir i have checekd the second param. Why do you not check `is_file` before `file`, that is something you missed when working with files.

Comment: This is `A1 -> Array[0][0], A2 -> Array[1][0]` very unclear, can you post an expected csv result?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions check the edit please, this shall be the csv result when you open it in notepad or other editor

Comment: Note the "\n" at the end of first row, and the ";" thats column delimiter in csv

Comment: Ok, mmh, You say `notepad` , did you know the difference between MAc/Linux line-breaks and windows line-breaks? `\r\n` vs. `\n` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006871/fputcsv-adds-a-line-ending-on-the-last-element

Comment: does this script writes all values -from other files- in one file ? or it's writing the first file data in first file only ?

Comment: Oh, im looking for a tree but only see a wood. Do use `a+` because `w` resets the writing file. Currently in each loop the file will be truncated and refilled.

Comment: Guys... i open a.csv, parse the rows in columns, write columns to SAME csv remote (and yes, i know the difference, i set from windows the delimiter from , to ;). Aint about the linke breaks or other stuff...

I wanna open a.csv parse the content, push it back handled in the same a.csv, open b.csv do the same trick and save to b.csv, do the ctrick for c.csv, d.csv and so on.

Is that clear?

Comment: i've tested your code on my machine and it's works fine and update the files, try to print the errors, it's maybe because permission issues! first time i've updated the files i got permission issues because the ownership of the file was not under www-data;

Comment: @hassan It doesnt throw any error... thats weird... It simply doesnt update other csv's except a single one. The csv files are hosted on a server so i update them there. I've listed all csv path and it seems like it update only the last one. The array is perfect, but doesnt update the others, only one from a list of 9 csv's